# gruntjs load external config

Tags: gruntjs

Ahoy grunt-masters!

I would like to load external config files into grunt so that I can do something like this:

`$ grunt dev:homepage`

and it would load in `homepage-config.json`, then run `watch`

`$ grunt dev:contact`

and it would load in `contact-config.json`, then run `watch`

Each config file would provide a particular setup for tasks: watch, jshint, concat, etc...

Inside my Gruntfile I have a task called `dev`

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', 'loads in external -config.json file, then runs watch', function(name) {

  grunt.initConfig(grunt.file.readJSON(name + '-config.json'));

  console.log(grunt.config('jshint.pageConfig.src') // correctly logs whatever had been specified in my external json file

  grunt.task.run('watch'); // correctly boots up watch with configuration specified by external file

});
```

Within that `dev` task the externally loaded config works just fine. That console.log would return what you'd expect, and the `watch` task kicks off with the externally specified setup.

My problem is that once that `watch` starts triggering tasks, those tasks no longer seem to have access to this externally loaded config. Somewhere between the `dev` task and the tasks triggered by `watch`, the dynamically loaded config gets blown away.

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening and how I might accomplish my goal?

Many thanks,
-James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `nospawn : true` in your watch task configuration so that the called tasks run in the same context. See [this section](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsspawn) of the docs for more info/examples.