# Grunt: How to compose two multitasks as another multitask plugin?

Tags: gruntjs

I have several npm modules that I'd like to use a common linting configuration for. I have jshint and closure linter working on a single project via Grunt. But copy/pasting the .jshintignore file and .jshintrc file for each project is going to be unwieldy, especially when something needs to change. So ideally I'd like to have a single grunt task that encapsulates the common configuration and can be loaded via

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mysuperlint');
```

Where `grunt-my-common-lint-tasks` is really just specific default configurations for both jshint and closure linter.

But I see no way to compose two existing grunt plugins into one where the only real composition is a merging of options as well as targets.

Is this possible?

Am I supposed to do something like:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('mysuperlint', function() {
    // Manual options merging?
    var opts = this.options({
        jshint: { src: 'scripts/**/*.js', options: { ... } },
        closureLinter: { src: 'scripts/**/*.js', options: { ... } }
    });
    grunt.config.set('jshint.dev', opts.jshint);
    grunt.config.set('closureLinter.dev', opts.closureLinter);
    grunt.task.run('jshint:dev');
    grunt.task.run('closureLinter:dev');
});
```

Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Basically this snipet looks fine. What is the problem?

Comment: It just felt very hacky at the time.

Comment: unfortunately they did not have built a better api yet. It was in discussion for the next bigger release

Comment: possible duplicate of [gruntjs load external config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359473/gruntjs-load-external-config)

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I could suggest a simple trick for your original problem:
You could have one global .jshintignore file and soft-link to it from each project.
It's kind of a hack but it's ways simpler